# Getting Error while Dexing. after upgrading flutter to 3.19.0

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

After upgrading to flutter 3.19.0 i am getting the following error while running my application on android it is working fine on ios and when i open only android directory in android studio and run the project in that case also it is working fine.

```
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform firebase-auth-22.3.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /home/munsif/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ba579288272952d282e3eb784bb3facc/transformed/jetified-firebase-auth-22.3.1-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform play-services-location-21.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /home/munsif/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c40ae925c2dff28a07b701244ea18adb/transformed/jetified-play-services-location-21.1.0-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform recaptcha-18.4.0.aar (com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha:18.4.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /home/munsif/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/6a9b2598905fd8f95f3e5a4db9115179/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /home/munsif/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ae0183353754275aa55a66ddf2de48d6/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
```

I tried adding these to gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

enabling multiDex like this in build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

add this line to build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

all these methods didn't solved my problem:
any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the compileSdkVersion solved my problem.

I changed `compileSdkVersion` in android/app/build.gradle

From

```
 compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
```

TO

```
compileSdkVersion 33
```

and the error gone.

**EDIT:**

I got the same issue when i change the compile sdk to 34 which flutter recommended me because i was using url_launcher and video_player which use compileSdk 34. and as i changed the compileSdkVersion to 34 i got the same issue again and that i solved by changing the `minSdkVersion` to 24 from 21

Change From

```
minSdkVersion 21
```

To

```
minSdkVersion 24
```

Thanks to [Johnyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6065375/johnyp)

Comment: This didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I solved it later by setting kotlin version to 1.7.21

Comment: Thank You :-) Solve the Problem 

Answer (score 8):

Changing minSdkVersion solved it for me. When having minSdkVersion 21 i had the exact same issue, increasing it to 24 solved the issue for me.

minSdkVersion 24

Comment: I do also spent hours on this. This is the right solution. No need to change  compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, spent couple of hours

Comment: no need to change to 24:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78149818/20032492