# Failed to transform firebase-auth-22.3.1.aar

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

**If I change to minSdkVersion 24, so run without error. I want to run min 19 or 21, but when I run I get these errors**

```
ERROR:D8: com.android.tools.r8.kotlin.H
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform play-services-measurement-api-21.5.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:21.5.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /home/---/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/49f516b4e0cb096adcf638dba9621d3b/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.5.1-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform firebase-auth-22.3.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /home/----/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ae74ccf15751eaa27d72e95a9c344e0a/transformed/jetified-firebase-auth-22.3.1-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
   > Failed to transform recaptcha-18.4.0.aar (com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha:18.4.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /home/----/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/ee3c9277022a423a54cec16e68f37c58/transformed/jetified-recaptcha-18.4.0-runtime.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
```

I'm using Flutter 3.19.2, and Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 built on February 22, 2024

gradle- 7.6

// android/app/buil.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example"
    compileSdk 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

   defaultConfig {
       
        applicationId  "com.example"
         
        minSdkVersion 19 
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
          signingConfig signingConfigs.release
          //  signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    bundle {
        storeArchive {
            enable = false
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
     implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.3"))
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'  
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth' 
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth'
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads'
     implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'      
}
```

//android/settings.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.4.2" apply false   
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.20" apply false  
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.1" apply false       
}
```

//pubspec.yaml

environment:

sdk: '>=3.1.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:

flutter:

```
sdk: flutter
```

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6

google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0

firebase_storage: ^11.0.0

cloud_firestore: ^4.0.0

firebase_auth: ^4.0.0

flutter_share: ^2.0.0

firebase_core: ^2.0.0

firebase_messaging: ^14.0.0

intl: 0.18.1

flutter_localizations:

```
sdk: flutter
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to find a solution yet?

Answer (score 3):

This error only happens when running the app locally (debugging). It builds fine for release with `minSdkVersion 21`.

The solution is to add the following to the `../android/app/src/build.gradle` file

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        //minifyEnabled true fixes this issue and allows you to use minSdkVersion 21
        minifyEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

It should now run locally with `minSdkVersion 21`.